# An open set that contains $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is an open set such that $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\subseteq A$, then $A=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: *Obviously* not.

Comment: If it were *closed*, though...

Comment: Take $A$ to be the irrationals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X\subseteq\Bbb Q$ a closed subset of $\Bbb R$, for example a singleton or $\Bbb Z$ or even far more complicated sets.

Then $A=\Bbb R\setminus X$ is an open set, and it contains $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$ as wanted.

For example one can pick for every $k\in\Bbb Z$ a rational sequence $k_n$ such that $k_n\to k$ and $k_n\in(k-1,k)$. Then the set $X=\{k_n\mid k\in\Bbb Z,n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\Bbb Z$ is closed, but very very complicated. And one can do even more. Much more.

Answer (score 6):

What about the set $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, following from Brian, you could take $\mathbb{R}$ less any set of *isolated* rational points, and this would work for $A$.

Comment: Doesn't have to be isolated either. $\Bbb R\setminus(\{\frac1n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{0\})$ is open as well.

Comment: Yup, just saw your answer!